# Unable to download .sqlite file from the server

Tags: php, ios, sqlite, ios7

I am using the following code which I referred from the php.net example:

```
<?php

// open the file in a binary mode
$name = './db.sqlite';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the database and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;

?>
```

When I try to run this PHP script from the URL of my browser, I get the warning:

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

My requirement is to basically set up a PHP script which I can use to download the .sqlite file in my iOS app. But I think first it must work directly through the URL. I am new to PHP so please guide me.

I also tried to find out why am I getting this warning in the following link:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1489/solve-php-e

But it didn't solve my problem.

Question 2.) I have planned to use NSURLSession to get the file in my iOS app's sandbox, once the PHP script is up and working. Is this the correct way?

Comment: fopen is most likely throwing an error, you should **do some checks** that fopen worked before setting the headers and continuing...

Comment: Could be a warning because you can't open ./db.sqlite so PHP have to send an output and you call header() after. More insidious, can be the file encoding if you're in UTF-8 with BOM: the invisible Byte Order Mark before you open the PHP tag will print and your header()s fail

Comment: I tried to print the contents of the file: $filecontents = file_get_contents($name);
print $filecontents;
All gibberish is getting printed out. Is it because of some kind of encoding? If yes, how should I print an encoded file?

Comment: Also, I just added a check as suggested: if($fp)
 echo "Opened";
else
 echo "Not opened";...It is printing "Opened". That means that the file is getting opened.

Comment: Why don't you just point at db.sqlite instead of a php script? The full header-already-sent error message would allow answers of why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit so that try out your suggestion? I did try to do this though: url/myfolderthatcontainsdbfile/db.sqlite...THis printed out the directory structure with the names of files in it in an HTML format

Comment: Even when I am simply trying to print out the file, some gibberish is getting printed. So it must be encrypted.

Comment: SQLite database files are not human-readable. Having them look like "gibberish" is expected if they're displayed as text in a web browser.

Comment: Thank you duskwuff. Can you please also tell me how can I correctly download one using PHP?

Comment: `I did try to do this though: url/myfolderthatcontainsdbfile/db.sqlite... THis printed out the directory structure with the names of files in it in an HTML format` Do you mean a folder listing? then the url used pointed as a directory, not a file. -1 because this indicates a problem: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` but the error message is truncated removing the bit that would allow anyone to say what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get my PHP working correctly so I found a workaround.

I used NSURLRequest to point directly to the sqlite file residing on the server and then used NSData to store the contents of it. I then stored the file in the sandbox of my app(simulator) and I am able to query the database.

Important lesson that I learnt: "SQLite database files are not human-readable"